# Cannot parse xml to List<> C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have this xml:

```
<NewDataSet xmlns="http://anonymous_link_here">
    <Table>
        <Name>Example</Name>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Name>Example</Name>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Name>Example</Name>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Name>Example</Name>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I'm trying to parse this xml to a `List<myClass>`:

```
        public static List<myClass> ConvertToList(string xml)
        {
            var objects= XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var objectsList= (from o in objects.Root.Elements()
                               select new myClass()
                               {
                                   Name = (string)o.Element("Name"),
                               }).ToList();
            return objectsList;
        }
```

myClass class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Table"), Namespace="http://anonymous_link_here"]

public class myClass{

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Name"), Namespace="http://anonymous_link_here"]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I don't know why I get the right count of elements in the `objectsList`, but the `Name` properties are null. I think there is something wrong with:
`Name = (string)o.Element("Name")`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you debugged through the code? In particular, I'd put a break point on the `Name = (string) o.Element("Name")`. Note that unless you're using actual built-in XML serialization, you don't need the attributes on your class. (I *would* suggest following .NET naming conventions though.)

Comment: use a debugger and execute your code step by step, so you can check the content of variables

Comment: I've just tested your code, and it works fine. Please provide a [mcve]. (In particular, if your *actual* XML contains namespaces, that would make a huge difference...)

Comment: Additionally: this has nothing to do with ASP.NET. I've removed the tag and will remove the occurrence in the title too.

Comment: @Cid good catch, made a mistake while anonymizing the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it does in fact contain a namespace, added it.

Comment: @JonSkeet debugging shows nothing for `(string)o.Element("Name")`

Comment: Okay, well that's the problem - `o.Element("Name")` looks for an element *without* a namespace, whereas yours has inherited the default namespace of "http://anonymous_link_here". I suggest you look up how to find elements with a namespace in LINQ to XML. (And please provide a [mcve] from the start next time.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, thanks a lot for the help. Fixed it by adding the namespace inside `o.Element(ns + "Name")`. Feel free to add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `o.Element("Name")` looks for an element called `Name` *without a namespace*, whereas your elements are in the default namespace for the document, which is `"http://anonymous_link_here"`.

Fortunately, LINQ to XML makes it easy to fix that using `XNamespace`:

```cs
XNamespace ns = "http://anonymous_link_here";
XElement child = parent.Element(ns + "Name");
```

With a bit of rewriting (and renaming to avoid `myClass`), this is how your method would look:

```cs
public static List<Table> ConvertToList(string xml)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XNamespace ns = "http://anonymous_link_here";
    return document.Root
        .Elements()
        .Select(element => new Table { Name = (string) element.Element(ns + "Name") })
        .ToList();
}
```

Or in an expression-bodied method:

```cs
private static readonly XNamespace TableNamespace = "http://anonymous_link_here";

public static List<Table> ConvertToList(string xml) =>
    XDocument.Parse(xml)
        .Root
        .Elements()
        .Select(element => new Table 
        { 
            Name = (string) element.Element(TableNamespace + "Name") 
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the code below; notice Name = o.**Value** not .Element,

```
public static List<myClass> ConvertToList(string xml)
{
     var objects = XDocument.Parse(xml);
     var objectsList = (from o in objects.Root.Elements()
                           select new myClass()
                           {
                               Name = o.Value,
                           }).ToList();
      return objectsList;
 }
```